# How does android studio run unit tests in multi module

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.0

My project has many modules , more than 20.

MyProject.

```
----ModuleA  
--------src   
------------androidTest   
------------test  
----dictionary  
--------ModuleB  
------------src  
----------------androidTest.  
----------------test.   
...  
...
```

I want to run all unit tests in one time with GUI.

But I can run unit tests only in one module now. By right click the test dictionary and select "Run tests in xxx".